# I am getting error Input Tensor is not an XLA tensor

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory, pytorch-lightning, tpu

I am trying to run Pytorch lightning code on Google colab with TPU. I am implementing the Seq2Seq and in the encoder part:

```
 ### Enocder class of the transformer. 

class Encoder (pl.LightningModule):
  def __init__(self, input_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, n_heads, pf_dim, dropout, device, max_len=10000):
    super().__init__()
    
    #self.device = device
    ## Token embedding table. 
    self.tok_embedding = nn.Embedding(input_dim, hid_dim)
    print (self.tok_embedding)

    ### positional embedding table. 
    self.pos_embedding  = nn.Embedding(max_len, hid_dim)

    ### define layers for multiple loop iteration. 
    self.layers = nn.ModuleList([EncoderLayer(hid_dim, n_heads, pf_dim, dropout, device) for _ in range (n_layers)])
    self.ffwd = FeedForward(n_embed)
    self.ln1 = nn.Linear (n_embed, n_embed)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
    self.scale = torch.sqrt (torch.FloatTensor([hid_dim]))


  def forward(self, src, src_mask):

    #src = [batch size, src len]
        #src_mask = [batch size, 1, 1, src len]
    print ("encoder device ", self.device)
    batch_size = src.shape[0]
    print ("encoder batch_size", batch_size)
    src_len = src.shape[1]
    print ("encoder src_len", src_len)

    pos = torch.arange (0, src_len ).unsqueeze (0).repeat (batch_size, 1)
    pos = pos

    #pos = [batch_size, src_len]
    #print ("tok embedd device", self.tok_embedding.device)
    print ("src in encoder device", src.device)
    print ("pos embedding device", pos.device)
    out1 = self.tok_embedding(src)
    out2 = self.pos_embedding(pos)
    src = self.dropout(( out1 * self.scale ) + out2)
    src = src
```

The line where I am defining the pos variable. That variable device is coming as cpu but everything else is on tpu device. So, I am getting the error that tensor is not on TPU. WHy that variable is on cpu? What is the workaround to prevent that?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create `torch.arange` tensor on TPU with something like this -

```
import torch_xla.core.xla_model as xm

device = xm.xla_device()
torch.arange(0, 100, device=self.device)
```